# is this implementation of merge sort good?

Tags: sorting, haskell, merge, mergesort

I've just started to learn Haskell last night and I've never used a functional programming language before.
I just want to know if my implemention of merge sort is good or bad and what exactly is good or bad.
Maybe it's even wrong - Well it does sort but maybe the Algorithm is not what I think what merge sort is.

Just tell me everything I could improve here. I by myself think its a pretty clear and simple implementation.
Thanks for your advice, here's the code :)

```
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge xs ys =  sorted : merge left right
                where 
                    sorted = if head(xs) < head(ys) then head(xs) else head(ys)
                    left = if head(xs) <= head(ys) then tail(xs) else xs
                    right = if head(xs) > head(ys) then tail(ys) else ys

msort [] = []
msort [x] = [x]
msort xs = merge (msort left) (msort right)
            where 
                left = take (div (length xs) 2) xs
                right = drop (div (length xs) 2) xs
```

Comment: in the two lines, `sorted =` and `left =`, you must use the same comparison; either `<` or `<=`, but both must be the same (and the third line, `right =`, will have to use the other variant accordingly).

Comment: Oh sorry, just saw that comment now. I guess you're right. If I understand it right, this little mistake only affects the stable/unstable attribute of the algorithm right? As it really doesn't matter if I take head(xs) or head(ys) if they are equal.

Comment: No, of the two equals you'll drop one completely and have the other twice in your output: `merge [(1,1),(2,1)] [(1,2),(2,2)] = (1,2):merge [(2,1)] [(1,2),(2,2)]` for a pair-like datatype which compares on first sub-element only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, first of all, we can rewrite merge to be a little more elegant using pattern matching

```
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge xs@(x:xs1) ys@(y:ys1)
    | x <= y = x : merge xs1 ys
    | otherwise = y : merge xs ys1
```

In general you should avoid using `head` and `tail` since they are a bit unsafe (they raise an error for the empty list) and use pattern matching whenever possible.

The implementation of `msort` is pretty much spot on, except that we can split the list in a more efficient way. That's because `length xs` - takes O(N) to complete. The compiler might save you and cache the result of the `length` call so that the second call to `length` won't traverse the list again. But the `take` and `drop` will pretty much cause another two traversals thus splitting the list using 3 traversals which may prove to be expensive. We can do better by splitting the list in two lists - the first one containing the elements on the odd positions and the second list with the elements placed on the even positions, like so:

```
msort [] = []
msort [x] = [x]
msort xs = merge (msort first) (msort second)
    where
        (first, second) = splitInHalves xs
        splitInHalves [] = ([], [])
        splitInHalves [x] = ([x], [])
        splitInHalves (x:y:xs) =
            let (xs1, ys1) = splitInHalves xs
            in  (x:xs1, y:ys1)
```

This gets you the same Merge Sort in O(NlogN) time. It feels different because you would probably implement it in place (by modifying the original list) in an imperative language such as C. This version is slightly more costly on the memory, but it does have it's advantages - it is more easy to reason about, so it is more maintainable, and also it is very easy to [parallelize](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/lang-parallel.html) without being concerned of anything else except the algorithm itself - which is exactly what a good programming language should provide for the developers that use it.

**EDIT 1 :**

If the syntax is a bit much, here are some resources:

- [Pattern Matching](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) - the bit with the `@` symbol is called an *as-pattern*. You'll find it in there
- `let` is a keyword used to declare a variable to be used in the expression that follows it (whereas `where` binds a variable in the expression that precedes it). More on Haskell syntax, including guards (the things with `| condition = value`) can be found here, in this chapter of [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)

**EDIT 2 :**

@is7s proposed a far more concise version of `splitInHalves` using the `foldr` [function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:foldr):

```
splitInHalves = foldr (\x (l,r) -> (x:r,l)) ([],[])
```

**EDIT 3 :**

Here is another answer which provides an alternative implementation of merge sort, which also has the property of being [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability):

[Lazy Evaluation and Time Complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057658/lazy-evaluation-and-time-complexity/12057921#12057921)

Hope this helps and welcome to the wonderful world of Functional Programming !

Comment: `splitInHalves = foldr (\x (l,r) -> (x:r,l)) ([],[])`

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your precise feedback.
I'm afraid I can't understand everything right now as I have not yet read about all the syntax ("let ... in ..." or "@") but I'll look these things up and try to understand your code :)

Comment: @is7s - yep this is more concise, but for a newcomer in FP I think the more verbose version is better for starters.

Comment: @Nocta - oh, no problem. I've added some links that explain the various constructs used.

Comment: Thanks :)
But couldn't you also achieve the same thing that @ does if you just write x:xs in the right side of the function?

Meaning i could also avoid using head and tail without having an "ugly" @? What is the advantage here?

Comment: Note: `splitInHalves` as implemented makes the sort unstable

Comment: @Nocta - the advantage is that it avoids creating the list again, since the (:) will allocate memory for another list node. But, yes, it's practically the same code.

Comment: @singpolyma - it is indeed. Can you propose a solution which is still efficient and it is also stable ?

Comment: The `splitInHalves [x, y] = ([x], [y])` case is superfluous, isn't it?

Comment: @M.A.D. stable mergesort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057658/lazy-evaluation-and-time-complexity/12057921#12057921 .

Comment: @is7s is this a widely known piece of lore? I've seen it first here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942630/splitting-a-list-of-items-into-two-lists-of-odd-and-even-indexed-items/7945580#7945580 , in F#. Also, wouldn't it be better written with lazy pattern, `foldr (\x ~(l,r) -> (x:r,l)) ([],[])` as a matter of style?

Comment: @WillNess - thanks. this is quite an interesting implementation. I'll add a reference to it.

Comment: @Landei - yes it is, I've made the fix. Thank you !

Comment: @M.A.D. that's a "bottom up" mergesort. (also, beware the rule of 10 edits: your answer will turn into pumpkin, er, community wiki post, and you won't collect any new rep on it). :)

Comment: Ah okay now it makes sense :) 
Still got some problems with foldr tough.
I'm able to understand the result of this self-written example
test = foldr (\x y -> 2*(x+y)) 5 [1, 2, 3]

But what is missing here: One can't pass arguments to 'test'.
How is this achieved in 'splitInHalves'?

Comment: Another question that comes up into my mind when i read this stuff about stable and not stable:
How can I pass data to msort that actually needs to be sorted in a stable way? Right now I know I can pass Strings, Lists of Strings, Lists of Ints, ... But none of these types has something like a "relative order" between elements that have the equal value in terms of the sort algorithm. 
In other words: How can I for example sort tuples by their first element and ignore the second element to actually create a case in which stable / unstable is a matter?

Comment: @Nocta `foldr` is easy to visualize, as `foldr (+) 0 [a,b,c...z] = a + (b + (c + ... (z + 0) ...))` for some kind of generalized `(+)` and `0` (which must go together of course). IOW, when the combining function `(+) = \a b -> a + b` is called, `b` represents the *result* of calling `foldr` on the rest of the list. Check out the WP article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_on_lists .

Comment: @Nocta - also look at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application to understand is7s's version

Comment: @Nocta notice the `splitInHalves` is defined with one less argument. Because the type of `foldr` is known, the type of `splitInHalves` is automatically deduced (*"inferred"*) by a Haskell implementation as `[a] -> ([a], [a])`. Which means it is a function, expecting of a list (of *anything*, denoted by a type variable `a`), and producing a pair of lists (each holding elements of the same type as the input list).

Comment: @Nocta - well, as you can see the `msort`function works kinda magically for most of the types you throw at it. This is because we are using the   operators provided by the Ord class: http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/libraries/base/Data-Ord.html. This makes the code work for all the predefined types which support ordering and for your own types which can support ordering as well if you implement the `Ord` class. But we can modify `msort` so that it uses an arbitrary comparison function like in the link in EDIT 3. You can pass a function which compares tuples using the first element only.

Comment: @Nocta about stability: if you sort compound data (say, pairs) and the comparison takes into account only one part of each element, e.g. (1,2) and (1,113) could be deemed equal. And in such a case, you might prefer to keep them in their original order.

Comment: Thanks for your patience guys, it's nice to learn new things that way.
@Will Ness: Thanks but I understood the basic concept of foldr, what I am missing is how it "magically" takes an argument without defining it in the function like 'splitInHalves Argument = blabla'
I also understand in which cases I would want a stable search but the question was more directed in the way: How does it work in Haskell? Well sorry, I guess my English is not that precise.

Comment: @M. A. D.: Got to take some time to think about the splitInHalves thing and considering the facts you gave me.
The msort thing kinda makes sense now even though hard to "fully understand" without some examples. But I'll leave it to that now and first try to understand the more basic things like the currying/partial application and how it affects the 'splitInHalves' function

Comment: @Nocta do consult http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying . Since `f x y z = code` is really `f = (\x y z -> code)` is really `f = (\x -> \y -> \z -> code)` is really `f = (\x -> (\y -> (\z -> code)))` is also `f x y = (\z -> code)` we can also write `f x y = newcode` and `f` will still be a function of 3 arguments, if `newcode` is a function of 1 argment. And `foldr g z` is a function of 1 argument: it expects a list. So `f = foldr g z` is a function of 1 argument. It expects a list. This is deduced from the type of `foldr` function.

Comment: @Nocta this is otherwise known as "eta-reduction": `f xs = code xs` can be reduced to `f = code`. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion .

Comment: @Will Ness: Your first post makes a bit sense to me and I'm starting to get the idea. But maybe I need to go back a step in my learning process and come to that topic again when I have read more about Haskell :)
Btw: Do I need advanced knowledge in subjects like "Logic" or can I understand the full concept of the language with a basic understanding of mathematics?

Comment: @Nocta - I would say that for starters there is no need for logics and mathematics any more than there is for any other programming language. However, as you progress and discover Haskell's type system some simple first order logic may help you understand the notations and some of the concepts. Also, to understand at a more advanced level one of Haskell's most powerful concepts - the monads - you will need to get into some http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory. But you'll cross that bridge when you'll come to it :)

Comment: Alright that sounds good :)
Thank you so far guys you really helped me but I need a break for today :D