# Recursive split-list function LISP

Tags: list, recursion, split, lisp, common-lisp

The split-list function takes a list and returns a list of two lists consisting of alternating elements of the input. I wrote the following:

```
(defun split-list (L)
  (cond
      ((endp L) (list NIL  NIL))
      (t (let ((X (split-list (cdr L))))
         (cond
             ((oddp (length L))
              (list (cons (first L) (first X)) (cadr X)))
             (t (list (first X) (cons (first L) (cadr X)))))))))
```

The output is as expected for odd numbered lists, the first list consisting of the 1st, 3rd, 5th etc elements and the second part consisting of the 2nd, 4th, 6th etc. With an even list however, the 1st, 2nd ,3rd.. are on the right of the returned lists with the rest on the left.

For Example:

```
(SPLIT-LIST '(a b c 1 2 3))
(SPLIT-LIST RETURNED ((b 1 3) (a c 2))
```

the order should be swapped. Is there a major flaw in my logic that I'm missing? Can I rectify this situation without making major alterations?

Comment: Programming questions / coding questions are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: calling `length` on each recursive call is not a good idea. It has to traverse the the list `l`each time.

Comment: Recursion is also not a good idea, since it limits the processing by the available stack size.

Comment: One possibly useful approach would be to move down the list one element at a time, keeping track of "odd or even position" and adding an element to one list or another.

Comment: recursion is always a good idea as a conceptual tool aiding our thinking while developing the solution. once the correct code is formulated, *iff* your language is limited in its handling of recursion, re-write it to use other means.

Comment: Verbose [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr): `[(juxt (op select @1 (range 0 : 2)) (op select @1 (range 1 : 2))) '(a b c 1 2 3)] -> ((a c 2) (b 1 3))`.

Comment: Shorter [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr): `(transpose (tuples 2 '(a b c 1 2 3)))`.   `tuples` with an argument of `2` shores up consecutive pairs within the list into `((a b) (c 1) (2 3))`. Then `transpose` does exactly what we want (just think of this list of pairs as the columns of a matrix).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can rectify the problem without major modifications.

1. Add a case for `(endp (cdr L))`
2. Do the recursive call on `cddr L`
3. After that, the else case will always have two new elements, one to cons onto each list; there is no more need for the `length` call

Answer (score 3):

First, when you have `cond` with only one test and a default `t` clause, please use `if` instead.
 Also, you are using `first`, but `cadr`; `second` is more readable in your context than `cadr`.

Now, the order is swapped for even lists. Try to perform a step-by-step execution. It might be a little tedious by hand but this is useful to understand what happens. I personally  prefer to use the `trace` macro: `(trace split-list)`. Then, running your example:

```
   0: (split-list (a b c 1 2 3))
    1: (split-list (b c 1 2 3))
      2: (split-list (c 1 2 3))
        3: (split-list (1 2 3))
          4: (split-list (2 3))
            5: (split-list (3))
              6: (split-list nil)
              6: split-list returned (nil nil)
            5: split-list returned ((3) nil)
          4: split-list returned ((3) (2))
        3: split-list returned ((1 3) (2))
      2: split-list returned ((1 3) (c 2))
    1: split-list returned ((b 1 3) (c 2))
  0: split-list returned ((b 1 3) (a c 2))
```

Unclear? Try with an odd-sized list:

```
   0: (split-list (a b c 1 2))
    1: (split-list (b c 1 2))
      2: (split-list (c 1 2))
        3: (split-list (1 2))
          4: (split-list (2))
            5: (split-list nil)
            5: split-list returned (nil nil)
          4: split-list returned ((2) nil)
        3: split-list returned ((2) (1))
      2: split-list returned ((c 2) (1))
    1: split-list returned ((c 2) (b 1))
  0: split-list returned ((a c 2) (b 1))
```

*It seems you always store the innermost result in the left list!*

A possible recursive implementation goes roughly like this:

```
(defun split-list (list)
  (if (endp list)
      '(nil nil)
      (destructuring-bind (left right) (split-list (cddr list))
        (list (cons (first list) left)
              (if (second list)
                  (cons (second list) right)
                  right)))))
```

But this can blow the stack for sufficiently large inputs. For your information, here is a simple non-recursive approach with `loop`:

```
(defun split-list (list)
    (loop for (a b) on list by #'cddr
          collect a into left
          when b 
            collect b into right
          finally (return (list left right)))
```

And since you probably will have to split your list into more than 2 lists in your next assignment, a more generic version, still with loop:

```
(defun split-list (list &optional (n 2))
  (loop with a = (make-array n :initial-element nil)
        for e in list
        for c = 0 then (mod (1+ c) n)
        do (push e (aref a c))
        finally (return (map 'list #'nreverse a))))

(split-list '(a b c d e f g) 3)
=> ((a d g) (b e) (c f))
```

If you want to have fun with circular lists, you can also try this, which works for any sequence, not only lists:

```
(defun split-n (sequence &optional (n 2))
  (let* ((ring (make-list n :initial-element nil))
         (head ring)
         (last (last ring)))
    (setf (cdr last) ring)
    (map nil
         (lambda (u)
           (push u (first ring))
           (pop ring))
         sequence)
    (setf (cdr last) nil)
    (map-into head #'nreverse head)))
```

If you plan to investigate how this works, evaluate `(setf *print-circle* t)` first.

Answer (score 2):

One of the very common idioms in recursive list processing is to build up result lists in reverse order, and then to reverse them just before returning them.  That idiom can be useful here.  The essence of your task is to return a list of two lists, the first of which should contain even-indexed elements, the second of which should contain odd-indexed elements.  Here's how I'd approach this problem (if I were doing it recursively).  The idea is to maintain a list of even elements and odd elements, and a boolean indicating whether we're at an even or odd position in the overall list.  On each recursion, we add an element to the "evens" list, since the current index of the current list is always zero, which is always even.  The trick is that on each recursive call, we swap the evens and the odds, and we negate the boolean.  At the end, we use that boolean to decide which lists are the "real" evens ands odds list.

```
(defun split-list (list &optional (evens '()) (odds '()) (evenp t))
  "Returns a list of two lists, the even indexed elements from LIST
and the odd indexed elements LIST."
  (if (endp list)
      ;; If we're at the end of the list, then it's time to reverse
      ;; the two lists that we've been building up.  Then, if we ended
      ;; at an even position, we can simply return (EVENS ODDS), but
      ;; if we ended at an odd position, we return (ODDS EVENS).
      (let ((odds (nreverse odds))
            (evens (nreverse evens)))
        (if evenp
            (list evens odds)
            (list odds evens)))
      ;; If we're not at the end of the list, then we add the first
      ;; element of LIST to EVENS, but in the recursive call, we swap
      ;; the position of EVENS and ODDS, and we flip the EVENP bit.
      (split-list (rest list)
                  odds
                  (list* (first list) evens)
                  (not evenp))))
```

```
CL-USER> (split-list '())
(NIL NIL)
CL-USER> (split-list '(1))
((1) NIL)
CL-USER> (split-list '(1 2))
((1) (2))
CL-USER> (split-list '(1 2 3))
((1 3) (2))
CL-USER> (split-list '(1 2 3 4))
((1 3) (2 4))
CL-USER> (split-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
((1 3 5 7 9) (2 4 6 8 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is always a good idea, as a conceptual tool aiding our thinking while developing a problem's solution. Once the correct code is formulated, *iff* your language is limited in its handling of recursion, re-write it to use other means.

A modern implementation of a Scheme-derived language (Scheme is a kind of a Lisp, right?), Racket has unlimited recursion, implementing call stack on the heap. As such, recursive code for a recursive algorithm is perfectly fine.

Correctness / <s>serenity</s> simplicity first, efficiency later!

The simple solution for your requirements is (in the executable "pseudocode" of Haskell)

```
    foldr (\x [a, b] -> [x:b, a]) [[], []]
```

I first saw this neat trick in an [old F# <s>(IIRC)</s> answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945580/849891) by [user *ed'ka*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394253/edka) <s>(IIRC)</s>; quite a few years back. (But *actually* it appears to have been [in haskellwiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/index.php?title=Blow_your_mind&oldid=2630) since more or less forever).

Coded in direct recursive style in Scheme, it is

```
(define (split xs)
  (cond
    ((null? xs) (list '() '()))
    ((split (cdr xs)) => (lambda (acc) 
         (list (cons (car xs) (cadr acc))   ; always in the first subgroup!
               (car acc))))))
```

The list's head element must appear in the first subgroup. No need to exert ourselves trying hard to arrange for it to happen, just say it, and it happens just because you said so, all by itself, because of the magic that is *recursion* !

```
(split '(a b c 1 2 3))
(split '(a b c 1 2))

; '((a c 2) (b 1 3))
; '((a c 2) (b 1))
```

A side note: I decided to never use *`if`* again, in preference of *`cond`*, because an *`if`*'s clause in itself says nothing about its activation conditions - we must *count*, of all things, to know which is which.  With *`cond`* it's plain, and it is right there at the clause's start.

---

It is easy enough to amend this to produce e.g. a *three*-way split, with

```
(define (split3 xs)
  (cond
    ((null? xs) (list '() '() '()))
    (else (apply
           (lambda (a b c)             ; Scheme-style destructuring
             (list (cons (car xs) c)   ; rotate right:
                   a                   ;   xs's 2nd elt to appear in the 2nd group!
                   b))                 ;   head element of (cdr xs) is in `a`
           (split3 (cdr xs))))))       ; the recursive result

(split3 '(a b c 1 2 3))
(split3 '(a b c 1 2))

; '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
; '((a 1) (b 2) (c))
```